# Shippo c# api and ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, shippo

I am trying to integrate the shippo API into an older web project that is used on our MC9090s.  I have successfully implemented it in a test winforms project no problem, but when I try to utilize it within this web project I get a System.Net.WebException "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."

I get this error even if I just run simple code like:

`Shippo.APIResource api = new Shippo.APIResource("xxx");
Shippo.ShippoCollection carrierAccounts = api.AllCarrierAccount();`

Anyone have any idea why this would happen?

The project is running .Net 4.6.2, same version as the test app.

Thanks